Doob's inequality for Wiener Fields
Let $W^{(n)}$ a $n-$fold Wiener field, i.e. a Gaussian separable real-valued field on $\mathbf{R}_{+}^N=\left\{t=\left(t_1, \ldots, t_N\right): t_i \geq 0\right\}$ with zero mean and covariance function
$$
\mathrm{E}\left[W^{(N)}_{t_{1},...,t_{N}} W^{(N)}_{s_{1},...,s_{N}}\right]=\prod_{i=1}^N t_i \wedge s_i
$$
where $t \wedge s=\min (t, s)$. For $N=1$ this simply define a Wiener process (Brownian motion) and by Doob's inequality we know that, for $p>1$,
$$E\left[\max _{0 \leqslant t \leqslant T}\left|W^{(1)}_t\right|^p\right]\leqslant\left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)^p E\left[\left|W^{(1)}_T\right|^p\right].$$
I am looking for a generalization of this inequality for any $N$. For the $N=2$ case (Brownian sheet), these lecture notes give a similar formula (theorem 1.3) : https://www.math.utah.edu/~davar/UW/notes.pdf
From these results, my guess is that we have something like, for $p>1$,
$$E\left[\max _{(t_{1},...,t_{N})\in[0,T]^{N}}\left|W^{(N)}_{t_{1},...,t_{N}}\right|^p\right]\leqslant\left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)^{dp} E\left[\left|W^{(N)}_{T,...,T}\right|^p\right].$$
Do similar results are shown in available references ? Or maybe it can be shown easily from well known theorem ?
EDIT : I think the technic of proof used in the lectures notes for $N=2$ can be generalized for all $N$, still I am interested in a citable result to avoid reproving it.
